# Space isn't replaced

Tags: c, string

I'm learning [c](/questions/tagged/c) by reading K&R. I'm trying to be methodical and make sure I understand the concepts before moving on.

One of the exercises asks to write a program that copies the input to the output "replacing each string of one or more blanks with one blank."

I have written the following, but it outputs the input verbatim even when multiple consecutive blanks exist:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()

{
    int c, d, a;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) 
    {
        a = c;

        if (c == ' ' && d == ' ')
        {
            a = 0;
        }

        d = c;

        putchar(a);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not very far into the book, so I feel like I'm missing something really simple...

Comment: You should start by using meaningful variable names. This aint the 80s anymore :)

Comment: Recheck the logic. There are as many `putchar` calls as (successful) `getchar`, so no characters will be dropped. As for `it outputs the input verbatim` I don't think it does that.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I agree completely. However in this example, alphabetical names actually made the conversation easier.

Comment: Putchar(0) is not the same as not writing anything. To remove blanks, just don't write. Also, `d` is not initialized, so it gets checked before it has a value if the input starts with a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good points in the comments:

- use meaningful variable names
- `putchar(0)` is not the same as not writing anything
- all variables need to be initialized

I would make one more suggestion:

- the `while` loop should read the character and check for EOF as shown below

(Assuming that you have the 2nd edition of K&R, see section 1.5.1 on page 17 for a detailed explanation.)

Here's how I would write the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int oldc = 'a';

    while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        if (oldc != ' ' || c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        oldc = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your solution is much more elegant than mine!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, although I'm not completely satisfied with my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()

{
    int c, d;

    d = 'a';
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) 
    {

        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);

        if (c == ' ' && d != ' ')
            putchar(c);

        d = c;

        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Thanks to those who commented. Besides the issues with my logic, I was falsely assuming that `putchar(0)` is the same as printing a zero-length string.

Comment: This one is actually pretty close to the accepted answer. All you have to note is that in general `if(x) do_that(); if(!x && y) do_that();` is equivalent to `if(x || y) do_that();`.

Comment: @dxiv Yeah, I saw that. I feel like an idiot for not realizing this sooner, ha.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code because you are testing `d` before it is initialized the first run of the loop

Here is solution I came up with quickly. It's not the most efficient but I believe it's simple to understand and only works in terms of the variable `c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        if(c == ' ') /* If the last character was a space */
        {
            do /* Then keep getting new characters and overwrite */
            {
                c = getchar();
            } while(c == ' '); /* as long as spaces keep coming */
        }
        else
            c = getchar(); /* if a space wasn't received, then just get the next */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As stated above, once the program receives a space, it enters a loop which overwrites C until the next non space character is found, and then it just prints whatever is in C.